# Subdomain still times out after being set up a month ago

Tags: subdomain, ip-address

I would like to use the subdomain `www.high-res.domain.com` to be accessed by external customers with specific permissions to access the site (like FTP).  We use Network Solutions to house `domain.com`. We recently added a new IP address to point to `www.high-res.domain.com`. I gave the IP address to the company that hosts our website. I pinged `www.high-res.domain.com` and it points to the correct IP address but still times out. It’s been a few weeks now and when you ping it, it still times out.

```
C:\>ping XXX.XXX.X.XXX

Pinging XXX.XXX.X.XXX with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for XXX.XXX.X.XXX:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss).
```

`tracert` times out as well. I even went to DNS tools and a few other sites for checking this and it shows the same thing.

I recently went into the DNSmgmt on our server (wink2k3sp1) and created an `A` record under the DomainDnsZones which translated to a `CNAME` when you look at it. Under the domain it has two entries, one to the subdomain and the other to the website host.  Each has separate IP addresses. Is this correct?

Comment: Getting the DNS right won't help you if the actual server is not available on a particular IP address. Where is the server on this new IP address?

Comment: There is no server for this IP address, the website host told me to get an IP address so they could use it as a subdomain for the webpage they were creating for us. From what I was reading online when you do things like that you, put the additional IP at the domain registration (Network solutions). Was I still doing the wrong thing?

Comment: The website people have to configure the server to work at that IP address. It sounds like you've done all the right things, but you need them to do something at their end.

Comment: Paul, thank you for helping...I wish they'd hurry on their end.

Comment: You can't just pick an IP address and add it; you need to request an IP address be registered to you (and the machine then set up with that IP). If the high-res.domain content is located on the same physical machine as www.domain, you don't really need a new IP and just use [virtual name-based hosting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)

Comment: Try using `NSLOOKUP` on the subdomain.  Depending on your hosting plan, you need to add a new A Record in the DNS section to point to the subdomain.  I did this this week.  Should take no longer than 2 days

Answer (score 1):

Your web host will not be able to take control of any IP address that you chose.  It is very unusual that you would specify the IP address and then have them try to host something there.

The usual way that it works is that your host chooses the IP address, tells you what that IP address is, then you put the IP address that they have given you into the DNS system.

It sounds to me like you have chosen an IP address that your host does not control.  In that case, there is nothing that the host can do to make that IP address "live" for you.  Rather you will need to ask them what IP address they can actually host your server on.